# Azure SQL Data Discovery and Classification Unable to Discovery Our Tables

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-log-analytics, azure-security

Data Discovery & Classification is built into Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics. It provides basic capabilities for discovering, classifying, labeling, and reporting the sensitive data in your databases.

However, the Data Discovery and Classification engine fails to identify a bunch of tables. At the moment, it is only able to identify our contacts table.
[image]

Can someone let me know if the table needs to be in a certain format for the Data Discovery to able to discover and classify tables?

If not, can someone explain why the Data Discovery and Classification engine is unable identify/discover other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Data Discovery and Classification identify based on Information types of columns. It works using the column names.

To directly add classification, you can follow below steps:

[image]

**Manage Information Types**

To detect tables, it uses Information types of columns which are built-in as shown below it will match pattern with your column name and detect it. you can edit this Information Type by clicking on `Configure` and add the pattern of your column name and save it.

[image]

After creating table with column name matching the patterns mentioned in the Information Type It is successfully detecting tables.

[image]